# Store changelog in openldap database

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap

I want to store changelog in my OpenLDAP database which contains details like this:[: This is a sample entry from another system which is using openLDAP to store all the information about changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHlsy.png)

I configured audit log but they are storing less information and it is in LDIF file not directly in the OpenLDAP database. I am new to OpenLDAP please help, I have no idea how to configure this.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `accesslog` overlay. https://openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-accesslog&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release&arch=default&format=html